# how to get an amazon hosted rtmp stream to work on iOS using jwplayer

Tags: javascript, ios, amazon-web-services, jwplayer, rtmp

I'm using amazon cloudfront to host mp4 videos. I must use JWplayer (6.7) to stream the content. It all works fine on a desktop browser where Flash is used, but it does not work on iOS devices (The video URL is only valid for like 2 minutes but that works fine.).

This is my setup call. What am I doing wrong?

```
jwplayer('video').setup({
    image: '/path/to/some/image.png',
    file: 'rtmp://s3e5mnr1tue3qm.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/2012_01_28_Hertha_HSV_Interview…e9roPYjl7bszSh~pGqvPAwPaZwJXZAizZVCwjCQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIAS7DDQFOAHAHOTQ',
    primary: 'flash',
    flashplayer: '//d12q7hepqvd422.cloudfront.net/global/js/jwplayer6.7.4071/jwplayer.flash.swf?v=2',
    html5player: '//d12q7hepqvd422.cloudfront.net/global/js/jwplayer6.7.4071/jwplayer.html5.js?v=2',
    width: '940',
    height: '403'
});
```

This is based on the jwplayer docs to be found here: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28854/using-rtmp-streaming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fall back to a stream that iOS can play.

For example - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29394/hls-with-mp4-fallback

Just make the 1st source rtmp, 2nd source a http served mp4 (rtmp does not work in html5 video).

Comment: Ah ok. So how do I define that in the setup call? Or should I just change the URL protocol from rtmp to http?

Comment: See the sample code from the link, it has the two sources in the setup call.